# How to setup a maintenance page for all sites in IIS without a load balancer?

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5

When performing maintenance on our test server, I would like to simply redirect all traffic to all sites on the server to say the site's default site, where I have a maintenance page setup.

How can this be quickly accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a line in the sites web.config like this

`httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="http://someothersite.com/maintenance.htm" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Temporary"`

inside the `system.webServer`

When you need to go to maintenance mode, switch 'false' to 
'true' and all traffic to the site will be directed to the http://someothersite.com/maintenance.htm

Comment: Well, I don't want to do this for 30+ sites.  Where's the one location where I can update the config for IIS?

Comment: I had a huge problem using http redirect on my website for a maintenance page. It worked, but the customers kept getting the page even after I took down the redirect. Apparently browsers save redirect data so they had to manually clear their cache to get the site working again.